# Order of loading jars

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath, classloader, emr

Assuming there are two jars of different library versions on a classpath, e.g.

```
java -cp A-2.1.jar:A-2.2.jar ...
```

The package and class names in the first and second jars are the same, but  class implementation is different. Is it specified whether root jvm classloader will try to find a class in A-2.1 before A-2.2?

The problem is that AWS EMR adds hadoop jars to a classpath and some of its dependencies are of older versions. However, our application needs to use new versions of the same libraries, so will prepending the classpath with newer versions of libraries be enough or is shading a recommended practice in this case? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-config_hadoop-user-env.sh.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) documentation:

> The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is
>   important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the
>   directories in the order they appear in the class path variable.

That said, overriding the dependency JARs of another library will always be risky since the library provider might not have tested that combination, so you'll either need to ask them for reassurance, do your own testing, or shade/repackage the classes as you suggested.

Comment: Also, one way to see which classes are being loaded is to use the `-version:class` option to `java`.

Comment: This article (http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/when-and-how-a-java-class-is-loaded-and-initialized/) shows an example

Comment: @Brett Kail The referred documentation says "directories", does it imply direct file paths as well?

Comment: Yes, any file path is treated the same.